# jsf primefaces align datatable right next to sidemenu

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I'm using jsf 2.2 and primefaces 6.1. I try to position a dataTable with different columns on the right side next to a sidebar/ sidemenu, which is fixed on the left border of the Gui. I'm using templates and contentpanels to build up each component depending on the pageNavigation or UserInput.
But the problem is, that the dataTable is always shown below, not next to the sidemenu.
I have this code:

template/menuLeft.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
     <style>.menuButton {float: left;}</style> 
</h:head>

 <h:form>

    <p:menu toggleable="true">
       <p:submenu label="#{msg['orders']}">
           <p:menuitem value="#{msg['save']}" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
           <p:menuitem value="#{msg['updaten']}" icon="ui-icon-arrowrefres1-w"/>

    <p:submenu label="#{msgArticle['article']}">
        <p:menuitem value="#{msgArticle['article']}"  
        outcome="#{articleController.toArticleContent()}" />
        <p:menuitem value="#{msgArticle['articleFast']}"/>
     </p:submenu>
   </p:menu>
 </h:form>
 </html>
```

dataTable articleContent.xhtml:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
  <h:head>
  </h:head>
  <f:view locale="#{languageBean.locale}">
      <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/lib/templates/template.xhtml" >
          <ui:define name="contentPanel" >
              <p:dataTable var="article" value="#{articlesBean.articles}"  >
                  <f:facet name="header">
                      <h:outputText value="#{msg['deliveryMen']}" />
                  </f:facet>
                  <p:column headerText="Aktionen" >
                  <h:outputText value="verschied. Aktionen" />
                  </p:column>
                  <p:column headerText="#{msgArticle['picture']}">
                  <h:outputText value="Bild" />
                  </p:column>
                  <p:column headerText="#{msgArticle['articleNumber']}">
                  <h:outputText value="#{articleBean.articleNumber}" />
                  </p:column>
              </p:dataTable>
      </ui:define>
  </ui:composition>
  </f:view>
  </html>
```

template/content.xhtml:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
  <h:head>
     <title><ui:insert name="title">Default title</ui:insert></title>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
     <div id="menuLeft" style="float: left">
         <ui:insert name="menuLeft">
             <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/lib/templates/menuLeft.xhtml" />
         </ui:insert>
     </div>
    <div id="contentPanel" style="float: left">
       <ui:insert name="contentPanel">
           <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/lib/templates/contentPanel.xhtml" />
       </ui:insert>
   </div>
  </h:body>
```

JavaBean ArticleController.java:

```
  package controller;

  import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
  import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
  import dao.ArticleRepository;
  import dao.model.Article;
  import util.RoleUtil;

  @ManagedBean
  @ViewScoped
  public class ArticleController {

      private RoleUtil roleUtil = new RoleUtil();
      private ArticleRepository articleRepos = new ArticleRepository();

      public String toArticleContent() {
          return "articleContent";
      }
  }
```

When I click on the submenuButton "Article" the dataTable should be seen on the right side next to the sideMenu, but its shown below. I tried diverse css-Style commands like:

```
  <style>.menuButton {float: left;}</style>

  style="float: left"
  style="text-align: right;"

  <f:facet name="left">
     ...
  </f:facet>

  <f:facet name="right">
      ...
  </f:facet>

  style = "margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;"
```

but without any effect...

Can someone help me to aligne the datatable RIGHT to the sidemenu?

Comment: Look at the **generated** html... Try to 'fix' it in the browser with css and the browser developer tool. After you achieved that, backport to the xhtml. If you cannot achieve it in the plain html, try to find a base problem (e.g. how to align two `<div>`'s or whatever. JSF/PrimeFaces is in this regard primarily an html/css generator

Comment: the strange thing is, that when I change the "p" at  
<p:dataTable var="article" value="#{articlesBean.articles}"  >  to an "h", so it looks like:
<h:dataTable var="article" value="#{articlesBean.articles}"  >
      .... 
</h:dataTable>

it works. The dataTable is aligned to the right...... So it must be an explicit conflict ONLY with primeFaces.

Comment: I don't say it is not relatrd to the HTML and CSS that PrimeFaces generates, but you still need to find a solution in the clients-side html/css and 'backport that